# jquery add html append and remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi hope someone can help me with this,

I want to add and also remove html content from div.

breedte_cop stands for width of a jquery ui element from min 500 max 3000.

Initially I append 20 span (start val = 1000 / 50), and when extending it should with the for loop create more span.

Only I would like to remove it aswell when #breedte_cop gets to be 500 (= 10 span)

```
$.fn.PrevinbouwAddSpan = (function PrevinbouwAddSpan() {
            var bred = $('#breedte_cop').val();
            var hoog = $('#hoogte_cop').val();
            var Height = 9;
            var plus = hoog / 50;
            for(var i= 2; i <= hoog / 50; i++){
                $("#Inbot").append('<span class="left Inlams" id="inbouwLam'+ [i - 2] +'" style="height: '+ Height +'px; width: '+ bred / 5+'px; border-bottom: 1px solid #8B8B8B;"></span>');
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

If the question is simply how to remove a single span in a loop, try this:

```
 $("#Inbot").find('.Inlams').last().remove();
```

That removes only the last.Inlams span.